# TestNG Null Pointer Exception error when working on a page opened by a previous test case

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, testng

I am using TestNG and Page Object Model.
I have created some test cases. I see that the first two test cases are working. But, the third test case starts on a new page which is opened by the second test case. I am unable to interact with the new page, and getting a Null Pointer Exception error. Not sure what went wrong.

I have three Java classes Here.

This is my base class:

```
package MYQC_Reusable_Classes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

public class MYQC_Base_Class {

    public static WebDriver driver = null;
   // public static ExtentTest Logger = null;
  //  public static ExtentReports report = null;


    @BeforeSuite
    public void initialize() throws IOException {
     //   report = new ExtentReports("C:\\Users\\fhasan\\Desktop\\ExtentReport"+".html");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\fhasan\\Desktop\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();`enter code here`
        // add the precondition arguments
        options.addArguments("start-maximized", "incognito");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        // To maximize browser
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        // Implicit wait
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void timer(){
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    @AfterSuite
    // Test cleanup
    public void TeardownTest() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        MYQC_Base_Class.driver.quit();
    }
}
```

This is my page class:

```
package MYQC_Browser_Pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;

public class MYQC_Login_Page {

    WebDriver driver;

    // constructor that will be automatically called as soon as the object of the
    // class is created
    public MYQC_Login_Page(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "loginName")
    public static WebElement userNameField;

    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "loginPassword")
    public static WebElement passwordField;

    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "loginButton")
    public static WebElement clickLogin;


    //Method to enter username
    public void clickUserName() {
        userNameField.click();

    }

    public void enterUserName(String user) {
        userNameField.sendKeys(user);

    }

    public void clickPass() {
        passwordField.click();

    }

    public void enterPassword(String pass) {
        passwordField.sendKeys(pass);

    }

    //Method to click on Login button
    public void clickLoginButton() {
        clickLogin.click();
    }

}
```

This is my first test case which works fine:

```
package MYQC_TestCase_Classes;

import MYQC_Browser_Pages.CUST4_MYQC_Login_Selection_Page;
import MYQC_Reusable_Classes.MYQC_Base_Class;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class TC001_MYQC_Login_Selection_Button_Text extends MYQC_Base_Class {


    @Test()
    public void MYQC_Login_Button_Text() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        //creating anb object of the CUST4_MYQC_Login_Selection_Page
        CUST4_MYQC_Login_Selection_Page go_To_MYQC_Page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, CUST4_MYQC_Login_Selection_Page.class);

        // going to the cust4 myqc link
        driver.get("https://mmhcustfour.com");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Assert.assertEquals(go_To_MYQC_Page.buttonText(), "Login with Quickcharge Authentication");
        //System.out.print( go_To_MYQC_Page.buttonText());

    }

    }
```

This is my second test case (on the same page) which also works fine:

```
package MYQC_TestCase_Classes;

import MYQC_Browser_Pages.CUST4_MYQC_Login_Selection_Page;
import MYQC_Browser_Pages.MYQC_Login_Page;
import MYQC_Reusable_Classes.MYQC_Base_Class;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TC002_MYQC_Login_Selection_Test extends MYQC_Base_Class {

    @Test
    public void Go_To_MYQC_Login_Page_Test() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        //creating anb object of the CUST4_MYQC_Login_Selection_Page
        CUST4_MYQC_Login_Selection_Page go_To_MYQC_Page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, CUST4_MYQC_Login_Selection_Page.class);
        //Clicking on the button to go to the MYQC login page
        go_To_MYQC_Page.preClickLogin();
        // waiting few seconds to get a screenshot of the page
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        File src = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File("C:\\Users\\fhasan\\Desktop\\Selenium Screenshots\\MYQCLogin_Page.png"));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

}
```

This is my third test case class: (which creates the error)

```
package MYQC_TestCase_Classes;

import MYQC_Browser_Pages.MYQC_Login_Page;
import MYQC_Reusable_Classes.MYQC_Base_Class;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TC003_MYQC_Prepaid_Login_Test extends MYQC_Base_Class {

    //creating an object of the page

    MYQC_Login_Page login_page = PageFactory.initElements(driver,MYQC_Login_Page.class);


    @Test
    public void MYQC_Login() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        login_page.clickUserName();
        login_page.enterUserName("***");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        login_page.clickPass();
        login_page.enterPassword("***");
        login_page.clickLoginButton();


    }
}
```

After running the code, I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.click(Unknown Source)
at MYQC_Browser_Pages.MYQC_Login_Page.clickUserName(MYQC_Login_Page.java:30)
at MYQC_TestCase_Classes.TC003_MYQC_Prepaid_Login_Test.MYQC_Login(TC003_MYQC_Prepaid_Login_Test.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
```

Comment: Have you debugged ? It seems driver is not initialized and you are passing null

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
I have initialized the driver @BeforeSuite and it works fine on the first two test cases. I am wondering if I need to do anything before working on the current test case.

Comment: Where you are launching the page? driver.get(url)?

Comment: Why are your page object fields static?

Comment: @NandanA The launching page was done in the previous test case which works fine.

@Test()

    public void MYQC_Login_Button_Text() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        //creating an object of the CUST4_MYQC_Login_Selection_Page
        CUST4_MYQC_Login_Selection_Page go_To_MYQC_Page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, CUST4_MYQC_Login_Selection_Page.class);

        // going to the link
        driver.get("https://mmhasan345.com");

Comment: @AlexeyR. I tried with non static objects and still got the same error.

Comment: Call     `MYQC_Login_Page login_page = PageFactory.initElements(driver,MYQC_Login_Page.class);` inside `MYQC_Login()` and it should work. If it works please let me know I will post the reason

Comment: Still not working. getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

your username element is not found on your 3rd test, please do following actions

**at MYQC_Browser_Pages.MYQC_Login_Page.clickUserName(MYQC_Login_Page.java:30)**

1. Please **add screenshot** just before entering username,
2. Add **wait time** to load website completely.

still not helpful,
better you **should isolate** all your test methods.

1. no static properties
2. login and logout should be in before method and after method - test method should be independent
3. use common method for assertions so whenever get failed, automatically add screenshot

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. Still having the same issue.